# Why does pulse animation dont work properly on Edge?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, microsoft-edge

so I'm having problem with animation pulse in Microsoft Edge, at first I will describe what my goal is: my animation is pulsing dot (changing widht,height) in the middle of site. Everywhere it works perfect but in Edge the dot (while it animates) it's also dissapearing for a milisecond couple of times.

**HTML SNIPPET**

```
<div class="wrapper__index">      
        <a href="#hello"><img id="dot" class="wrapper__dot" src="images/pulsing_dot.svg" alt="Click to enter site"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS SNIPPET**

```
.wrapper__index {
 display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
 display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
 display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
 display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
 display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%; 
}

#dot {
align-self: center;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;

}

/****Dot animation*/

@keyframes pulse {
from {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
to {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
 }
}

#dot {
animation: pulse 1200ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Edge has this problem with svg but apparently changing animation to just plain CSS (not including svg) solves that.